# C# Call overloaded method parameters issue

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I have class with 3 methods:

```
IConnection CreateConnection(AuthType authentication, string user, string password);
IConnection CreateConnection(string ticket);
IConnection CreateConnection(IMetadata metadata);
```

And another class calling 2 of these methods:

```
IConnection connection = ticket != null ? manager.CreateConnection(ticket) : manager.CreateConnection(sso, user, password);
```

In calling class IMetadata's namespace is not included so this not known there. Compiler throws error on first calling (with ticket as a parameter) "The type 'IMetadata' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.". But no error on second call (with sso + user + password).
Seems like compiler somehow needs the knowledge of IMetadata to decide which one of 1-parameter method overload to call. Any ideas for solution?

Edit:
Sorry, I forgot to mention that this error emerged after removing the reference for IMetadata's namespace in calling class. We don't want the reference there (reasons unrelated to this issue).

Edit 2:
Adding second dummy parameter to overload with ticket parameter will solve the issue. But that's not the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: Reference the assembly containing the class in the consuming project?

Comment: You have to reference the assembly that contains `IMetadata`.

Comment: the most easiest but not perfect solution is to copy usings from the class with three methods(first code block) and paste it to the top of the file from second code block

Comment: @keipa Usings are pointless without adding the proper DLL to the list of references.

Comment: Note that this is nothing to do with *namespaces*. It's to do with *assembly references*. You're trying to use an assembly (X) that depends on the assembly (Y) that contains `IMetadata`. Assembly Y has to be present.

Comment: Yeah, this is a nasty problem, if the overload with IMetadata is added after you have created your project. It compiled fine, it still runs but if you want to recompile it you get an error. There is no other way than referencing Y, although you don't need anything from it. The compiler must decide which overload's signature matches your code. It can't know it for sure without knowing what IMetadata is (even if string is a special case, but image some other non-sealed object type).